# Temporary store image in php only while displaying on web page

Tags: php, symfony1

I want to fetch images from other site and display on my site. I want to store that images in my side temporary only at time of showing on page , so that user think images are coming from my site.is it possible? How? Thanks in advance.

ex:-
imagine there are some graphs generated in a server (some network monitoring graphs like smokeping )and those graphs are stored in a folder as `.png` format.

ex:- [imagine_this_url_has_a_graph](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping-demo/?target=World.USA.MIT) (but this is just a page)

so that user want to show those graphs in another web site.

Comment: "so that user think images are coming from my site" why?

Comment: This is either referred to as "caching" or "theft" depending on the source site's policy. If they don't mind you using their images, caching is a courtesy. If they do, I would be very careful.

Comment: ""so that user think images are coming from my site" why?"; take credit and onership of someone elses work?

Comment: I am new in web developing and i want to learn extraordinary things. My mind raised this question, so i am asking.

Comment: I imagine this could happen if images are generated from another server with a secured access.

Comment: @joetsuihk ,ex:- imagine there are some graphs generated in a server (some network monitoring graphs like smokeping )and those graphs are stored in a folder as .png format.

ex:- imagine this graph is a png. http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping-demo/?target=World.USA.MIT (but this is just a page)

so that user want to show those graphs in another web site.

Answer (score 1):

A simple caching system would do this. Given an HTML file like:

```
<body>
 <img src="imagesource.php?file=1" />
</body>
```

You could create your image data source (imagesource.php) like:

```
<?php
$files = array(
   'http://somesite.com/image_to_cache.gif',
   'http://somesite.com/image_to_cache2.gif'
);

if(!isset($_REQUEST['file']) || !isset($files[$_REQUEST['file']])) {
   header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
   exit;
}

// do we already have the cached file?
$requested_file = $files[$_REQUEST['file']];
$cache_dir = '/tmp/cached_images';
$cache_file = md5($requested_file);
$cache_path = $cache_dir . '/' . $cache_file;

header('Content-Type: image/gif');

if(file_exists($cache_path)) {
   readfile($cache_path);
   exit;
}

//need to create the cache.
$data = file_get_contents($requested_file);
file_put_contents($cache_path, $data);

echo $data;
```

This would cache the remote images locally if they haven't already been downloaded, and output them to the browser when requested.

Answer (score 0):

When the request for an image is made against your server, simply use `fopen()` to open the remote image, and `fpassthru()` to pass it through.

Answer (score 0):

use `fileread()` instead of `fopen()` if you want to output the image as it yours, otherwise, you will get an error.