# how to display the pic of a user from twitter

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am trying to make an sample web app using php mysql, where if a user enters a twitter username, he can see the profile pic of that particular user.

Which api could help to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the username, it's pretty easy to get the profile pic in Twitter: just check the url:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=twitterapi&size=bigger
```

... where 'twitterapi' should be replaced by the actual username.

Here's [more to read](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/profile_image/%3ascreen_name).

Comment: hi, one more doubt on ths.. i read a Tutorial in this site, which gets the demo here.. http://www.queness.com/resources/html/jstwitterhashtag/

But Twitter API says not to use as image source.. I want the twitter user profile pic to be shown to the left side of the tweet which is missing in the demo.

Comment: That's reasonable of Twitter to recommend not using the links as img src: they are not the image hosting site, after all. ) I suppose it's best to collect the picture by following the link, save in into some temporary location, then use that location as actual image source.

Comment: any means how you could do it? again this would only be displaying some 10 posts at a time and forget. So how to create a temporary storage. Is there a way out in MysQL or PHP

Comment: I think i found some answer over here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069959/temporary-store-image-in-php-only-while-displaying-on-web-page

Any ways Thanks.. for the Answer.